# C# - (Unity .NET project) How to include a reference script but should not be compiled

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, dll

I am newbie and I apologize in advance.
I have a Visual Basic solution with two projects inside
I would like to build a dll that excludes the script called "Group" in order to be able it to enter separately as source code (free to be modified ).
The problem is that if I exclude this file, the build does not run for missing references.

[image: solution1]

I tried another way by separating this script into another project and inserting it as a reference.

[image: solution 2]

After build, I thought to delete this dll and replace it with the source code. Error!!!(Unity Crash) Obviously the two dll did not reference a Group.cs file, but they refer to the DLL that contains the script called "Group."
I also tried to add this file as a link ... nothing
I am sure that my approach is wrong, but I'm no expert to understand the right way to go...Can someone help me?
Thanks so much!!!
Maurizio

Answer (score 1):

Put your file in a folder that begin with a dot "**.**"

Unity will ignore this folder during the compilation

Comment: Hello Ludovic, thanks for your ultra fast response. I know this feature but do not think that it solves my problem. My problem is to exclude from dll build a reference script and then add this script itself (as source code) within unity. Or maybe I do not understand Your Answer :)

Comment: @FreedomsGate So i am not sure to understand your question.

Comment: I want to cluster all my scripts in a DLL and leave out only one to be able to change it easily. Unfortunately, this script is a reference for all other scripts so if it is not included in the project, the DLL is not built because of lack of references. How can I do? I hope I have written better my question. I did not understand Your Answer in the literal sense of the phrase. If I offended you I did not do it and I apologize to you. You have shown me a path that I did not understand. :) Please Help me and.... Merry Christmas.